# How to get general user information with SteamID64?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

I am having problem with doing simple things using Steams 64 bit id.

How can i use SteamAPI to get the general information? like displaying name, username, location.

I used SteamAuth to make my social authentication on website, which only has the function, that gets the id.

Example:

```
steamid = GetSteamID64() 
username = GetUsername()
displayname = GetDisplay()
...
```

Does SteamAPI on have features related to this? is there any library in python that could support such thing?

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot of WebAPI methods to get details about a Steam user. You seem to be looking for [GetPlayerSummaries](https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamUser_GetPlayerSummaries_v2).

You'll need an [API key](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) to use it.